# Pressing 'Enter' in the Google Chrome Omnibar causes the event to fire on the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

When I try to load my web page and I press 'Enter' in the OmniBar it causes the event to fire on a field that I focus after the document finishes loading. This may have to do with Google Chrome's new feature where it starts loading the web page before you actually go to it.

I don't have this problem on Opera or Firefox.

Google Chrome bug? Is there anyway I can deal with it?

EDIT:
I tested without the auto-load feature, didn't make a difference.

Also, why would pressing enter in the OmniBar cause an event on an element focused on the DOM? Don't events propagate up the tree? Wouldn't the DOM contents be below the Omnibar? It fires both.

Comment: Do you mean that the blur event fires? Doesn't sound right at all. A link to a page showing the problem would help.

Comment: I don't think he's talking about the blur event, since he mentioned the return key.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you running and do you have an example page we can checkout?

Comment: Version:17.0.963.56

Sorry, I am running it locally and don't have access to a server.

Comment: Nearly 2 years later (in Chrome 32), and this is happening to me too. In my case it's on a Chrome extension new-tab page. I don't have any solution, can't even block it on a particular event property, as they seem to be the same. Wasn't happening 2 days ago (on Chrome 31), now it's suddenly started. The weird thing is that it's firing a keyup event-handler attached to a particular input... can't think how that could happen. EDIT: A minute after posting I saw this in the related links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991062/

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I have jQuery running on the page, and the field in question has an id, 'search'...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#search').focus();

});
```

Comment: There's no way possible for Chrome to mess with your page *after* it has loaded.

Comment: There shouldn't be, but it appears that it's doing it with mine.

If I press enter in the OmniBar it sends the enter event to the focused HTML element. My whole page is loaded inside $(document).ready() function.