# Keyup event listener fires when enter is pressed on Chrome's Ominbox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jquery

In chrome browser, when using this snippet:

```
  $(document).on('keyup', function(){
    alert("Hey");
  });
```

Every time I press `enter` in the url bar (for example when I cut and paste the url of the page itself) the event listener fires.
Why does it happen?

**EDIT:**

It surprised me because url bar is not in `document` (maybe in `window`?) and firefox does not have this behaviour. When I look for `e.target`, Chrome Inspector shows `body`.

I thought this could be caused by event bubbling so I tried this:

```
  $(document).on('keyup', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("Hey");
  });
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I prevent it from being triggered?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens because once you hit enter in the omnibox, the focus turns to the page. If you tried the same thing with `onkeydown`, the omnibox would change nothing, because as you said, it isn't a part of the document. One way to filter the omnibox's false event out would be to check that every `keyup` has a pair keydown.

```
<script>
var down = false;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (){
    down = true;
}, false);

document.addEventListener('keyup', function (){
    if(down === true){
        alert('It was from the page!');
    }
    else{
        alert('Omnibox. Ignore it.');
    }
    down = false;
}, false);

</script>
```

<strike>[Demo.](http://pastehtml.com/raw/c9d7kwd2j.html#typeHereAndHitEnter)</strike>

Make your own HTML page and try it preferably, because PasteHTML.com stuffs it into an iframe. For it to work correctly there, click on the text first to give the iframe focus.

[Demo.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/32930499/chromeOmniEnter.html#TypeHereAndHitEnter)
Remember to use your mouse to focus on the omnibox and type, not a keyboard shortcut. (That fires the onkeydown event, creating a false positive)

**Update:** As of Chrome 35, this doesn't happen anymore. I don't know which version they fixed it on, however.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for Chrome is simple: use `keypress` instead of `keyup`. This doesn't work in all cases (IE), so you may have to add a conditional to switch the type depending on the browser. However, this will solve your issue.

Note that looking for a specific keycode may negate your issue. Good luck.

Comment: `keypress` and `keyup` aren't the same thing.

Comment: @Amaan No, they aren't. However, they may be interchangeable depending on what functionality the asker is intending to implement with the key events.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter for the keycode ...if that helps...13 is enter key

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(event){
  if( parseInt(event.keyCode,10) !== 13 ){
      alert("Hey");
  } 
});​
```

Comment: I need that event for trigger other funny things inside my page ;)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to slightly delay the "keyup" event handler registration. This will skip the first "spurious" trigger that seems to happen in Chrome and Safari.

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(
        function() {
            console.log("Delayed event attachment");
            $(document).bind('keyup', log);
        }, 10);
});

function log(e) {
    console.log(e.target.localName);
}
```